# Office 2013 display bug

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

I've started getting a really weird bug in Office 2013 - every time I open any program in the suite I get the visual bug seen in the screenshot. The programs work, the problem seems to be purely visual, but I don't even know where to start with troubleshooting it. I reinstalled Office, to no effect. No other application is affected by the bug, and I'm running windows 7.

Has anyone seen anything like it, or have any idea what the issue might be?

Thanks

Wyatt

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You can try turning off Office's GPU rendering:

1. First open any Office 2013 program. For example open Word 2013. It'll open in new Start Screen mode. Click on "Blank document" option.
2. Now click on "File" menu present in the ribbon and then click on "Options" link given at the end of the left-sidebar.
3. It'll open Options window. Click on "Advanced" tab and scroll down a little. Look for following 2 options in "Display" section: 
   *Disable hardware graphics acceleration*
   *Use subpixel positioning to smooth fonts on screen*
   First option would be unchecked and second option would be checked by default.
4. Enable "Disable hardware graphics acceleration" option and click on OK button. Restart the program and it should fix the problem.

[source](http://www.askvg.com/disable-hardware-graphics-acceleration-and-fix-blurred-font-and-cursor-hanging-problems-in-microsoft-office-2013/)